# Create proper Git repositories from a Catchall (dirty) one

Tags: git, git-clone, shallow-clone

Let's call `my-dirty-repository` an existing Git repository containing lots of scripts which are not related. It is a catchall repository which needs to be *properly cleaned*.

As a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), let's say this repository only contains:

```
script1.sh
script2.sh
```

With various commits, which independently updated them, among several branches.

The aim is to create 2 100% independant Git repositories, with ONLY the history of kept files (references).

Let's call them `my-clean-repository1` and `my-clean-repository2`, the first one having only history about script1, and the second having only history about script2.

I tried 3 ways to reach my needs, without success:

- Simple clone + `git rm` to remove unwanted references
- [Sparse Checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout) which is not adapted at all
- [Shallow Clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

I'm pretty sure there is a way to perform it properly.

Comment: If these would be separate directories then you can use `git subtree`. However I do not know if you can do so for single files.

Comment: Look into [git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). I know it can do this on subdirectories. There should be a way to do it for individual files, but it might be more complex. GitHub provides instructions for directories [here](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/).

Comment: @Hauleth it would have been too easy, of course the most of scripts are all in the same root directory ;/

Comment: @mkasberg Thanks for your answer, I'll try that. But are you sure the history will be updated consequently?

Comment: Git filter-branch is a tool that programmatically re-writes git history. It will, essentially, recreate the repository from scratch containing only the commits you tell it to create. Unfortunately, it's a complex command that can be hard to get right for more complex use cases.

Comment: If you have a relatively short commit history (say, less than 50 commits), `git rebase -i` might be easier to work with - it is also a tool to re-write history, and it's easy to use it to remove commits.

Comment: @mkasberg Yes it was one of the way I though but the fact is the history contains several commits on script1, then script2, then script1 ... So it is not possible to reach the need with a rebase

Comment: That's the perfect situation for an _interactive_ rebase. Which will let you pick which commits to include. It should be very straight forward, particularly if commits tend to touch script1 or script2 but not both in the same commit.

Comment: @mkasberg thank you for your comments, I posted a complete answer with a perfect solution to my needs to share with community.

Comment: Does anyone have an alternative?

Comment: I updated link to my [new repository](https://gitlab.com/bertrand-benoit/cloneToCleanGitRepositories) on GitLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I created dedicated tool [cloneToCleanGitRepositories](https://gitlab.com/bertrand-benoit/cloneToCleanGitRepositories) to answer this need.

It is complete version of the old following one.

---

@mkasberg thank you for your advices about interactive rebase which is very interesting in some simple history situation.

I tried it, and it resolves my issue for some of the scripts for which I wanted a clean dedicated, independent, git repository.

Eventually, it was not enough for most of them, and I tried again another solution with [Git filtering system](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Finally, I wrote this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
##
## Author: Bertrand Benoit <mailto:contact@bertrand-benoit.net>
## Description: Create clean git repositories for each file in root of specified source Git repository, updating history consequently. 
## Version: 1.0

[ $# -lt 2 ] && echo -e "Usage: $0 <source repository> <dest root directory>" >&2 && exit 1

SOURCE_REPO="$1"
[ ! -d "$SOURCE_REPO" ] && echo -e "Specified source Git repository '$SOURCE_REPO' does not exist." >&2 && exit 1
DEST_ROOT_DIR="$2"
[ ! -d "$DEST_ROOT_DIR" ] && echo -e "Specified destination root directory '$DEST_ROOT_DIR' does not exist." >&2 && exit 1

sourceRepoName=$( basename "$SOURCE_REPO" )

# For each file in root of the source git repository.
for refToManage in $( find "$SOURCE_REPO" -maxdepth 1 -type f ); do
  echo -ne "Managing $refToManage ... "

  refFileName=$( basename "$refToManage" )
  newDestRepo="$DEST_ROOT_DIR/$refFileName"

  # Creates the repository if not existing.
  logFile="$newDestRepo/logFile.txt"
  echo -ne "creating new repository: $newDestRepo, Log file: $logFile ... "
  if [ ! -d "$newDestRepo" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$newDestRepo"
    cd "$newDestRepo"
    ! git clone -q "$SOURCE_REPO" && echo -e "Error while cloning source repository to $newDestRepo." >&2 && exit 2
  fi
  cd "$newDestRepo/$sourceRepoName"

  # Removes all other resources.
  FILTER='git ls-tree -r --name-only --full-tree "$GIT_COMMIT" | grep -v "'$refFileName'" | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 git rm -f --cached -r --ignore-unmatch'
  ! git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter "$FILTER" -- --all >"$logFile" 2>&1 && echo -e "Error while cleaning new git repository." >&2 && exit 3

  # Cleans remote information to ensure there is no push to the source repository.
  ! git remote remove origin >>"$logFile" 2>&1 && echo -e "Error while removing remote." >&2 && exit 2

  echo "done"
done
```

Usage :

```
mkdir /tmp/cleanRepoDest
createCleanGitRepo.sh ~/_gitRepo/Scripts /tmp/cleanRepoDest
```

In destination directory, it will create a new clean git repository for EACH file in root directory of specified source Git repository.
In each one, the history is clean and is only related to the kept script.

In addition it disconnects/removes the remote to ensure avoiding issue pushing back the changes to the source repository.

This way, it is easy to 'migrate' from a big dirty catchall Git Repository, to various clean ones :-)

Comment: @mkasberg what do you think about it?

Comment: @mkasberg I created dedicated tool [cloneToCleanGitRepositories](https://github.com/bertrand-benoit/cloneToCleanGitRepositories) on GitHub to answer this need.